# ResponseCache & AntiForgery conflict (VaryByHeader "Cookie")

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, caching

Ok, so I had this ResponseCache implemented in my project, with VaryByHeader = "Cookie"

- because in the Cookie header there's a cookie specific to each authenticated user - so when I change the user, the cache is busted.

Recently I've implemented an Anti-Forgery mechanism and I sent the token via the cookie, so it can be sent to all ajax requests as a header.

But my problem now is, you've guessed it, that this breaks my responsecache varying by the "Cookie" header - which contains all cookies.

What possible solutions do I have? I am thinking about putting the userID hashed in a new header and varying by that header? or some other than cookie method to send the XSRF-TOKEN?

Comment: Yes, I think you need change another header as vary by condition.

Comment: @Rena that's what I've ended up doing. I sent a cookie. In JS I break the cookie header, take what I need and create a new header ‍♀️